# Wordpress admin-ajax results in Error 302 redirect

Tags: ajax, wordpress, .htaccess

I have customized a plugin to make some ajax calls to admin-ajax.php and it works great. I copied the code over to another site and it no longer works for users who are not logged in.

From firebug:

```
POST http://<subdomain>.<server>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 302 Moved Temporarily 1.08s    

GET http://<subdomain>.<server>/ 200 OK
```

**edit**: The question is what could a theme possibly do to redirect ajax requests. The plugin has two hooks:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_em_ajax_getEvents', 'em_ajax_getEvents' ); // ajax for logged in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_em_ajax_getEvents', 'em_ajax_getEvents' ); // ajax for not logged in users
```

They both work fine on most sites, but one theme redirects requests from non logged in users somehow. Since these actions are specific to the plugin I am at a loss as to where to start looking.

**SOLUTION:** Big thanks to [Ronald Huereca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1230709/ronald-huereca) for the `add_action( 'init'` solution, that''s exactly where the offending redirect was hooking in, in an attempt to protect the admin area. Now I just need to find a safe fix here that doesn't compromise the theme's admin area, but also doesn't hamstring other plugins from allowing users to make anonymous ajax requests.

```
// stop users accessing the admin
add_action('init', array( $this, 'prevent_admin_access' ), 0);

function prevent_admin_access() {       

    if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), '/wp-admin') !== false) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 

        if(!user_can($current_user->ID, 'administrator') && ( !user_can($current_user->ID, 'contributor') ) ){
            wp_redirect(get_option('siteurl'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question does not say anything about the problem. Elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is just that I have no idea what could redirect ajax requests to admin-ajax.php  The actions are my own, they work fine, so where could one "get in the way" to cause that redirect.

Comment: Please ignore (delete comment doesnt work ;(

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had something similar occur in a theme.  The original coder was trying to prevent a non-admin user from being able to see the /wp-admin/ area.

Here's an example:

```
// Block Access to /wp-admin for non admins.
function custom_blockusers_init() {
  if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_admin() && !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_blockusers_init' ); // Hook into 'init'
```

I would check your theme for source code similar to what I have.

When you find the code, just add an extra conditional to make sure that a user isn't redirected if the **DOING_AJAX** constant is defined.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head, it was exactly that hook they had used; I have included the details in my question. Now I just need to think of a safe way to disable it without compromising the theme's admin area...

Comment: This makes the user always redirect to that same page

Comment: Had this exact thing happen but from a 3rd party plugin, was driving me nuts. This answer helped me narrow down what was happening and find the culprit and use an alternate solution.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is still a old question but you can have a look.

LETS DO THE CODE FASTER IF NOT INTERESTED ON EXPLANATION:

```
function redirect_non_admin_user(){
    if ( !defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && !current_user_can('administrator') ){
        wp_redirect( site_url() );  exit;
    } 
}


add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_non_admin_user' );
```

EXPLANATION:
The reason for this problem is that either some of the installed plugins are redirecting the non admin users to homepage or any pages when they try to access wp-admin like http://localhost/project/wp-admin . So this causing the problems .

SO when you redirecting non admins from accessing admin ,you can use the following code.This will also work in admin ajax call in frontend.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and this worked for me:

```
function mt_redirect_admin() {

if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && ( ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || ! DOING_AJAX ) ) {
wp_redirect( site_url() ); 
exit;
}
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'mt_redirect_admin', 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

change condition to

```
!user_can($current_user->ID, 'administrator') && ( !user_can($current_user->ID, 'contributor') ) && !is_ajax()
```

add `!is_ajax()`